# Running ionic cordova command gives error - Cannot find module './cordova'

Tags: git, cordova, github, ionic-framework, build

I just downloaded a previous commit off of github and i ran npm install but when I try to run `ionic cordova ...` it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module './cordova'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane-re/node_modules/ionic/dist/commands/index.js:16:165
```

When I try `ionic serve` it says:

```
Error: Cannot find module './build/util'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane-re/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

I have `cordova` installed globally, any help would be greatly appreciated - I am working against a clock.

**UPDATE**

A new one:

```
Eamons-MBP:ionicmane-re eamonwhite$ ionic package build ios
Error: Cannot find module './common'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane-re/node_modules/ionic/dist/commands/package/index.js:6:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Comment: Not exactly sure about this error. Is ionic app script installed else can you try installing it?

Comment: thanks for the response...trying `npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev`

Comment: that was good for ionic serve...trying to run on device still gives cordova error...i already tried uninstalling cordova globally and installing again

Answer (score 0):

I did a fresh install with `npm` and it worked fine.